# Given a finite set of primes $(q_i)$ is the set of all primes reachable by common differences finite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic, integers

Let $Q =(q_i)$ be a finite set of prime numbers in $\Bbb{Z}$.  Define $\hat{Q}$ to be the unique largest set of primes reachable by adding an offset to $Q$:

$$
\hat{Q} = \bigcup_{a \in \Bbb{Z} \\ Q + a \text{ all prime}} (Q + a)
$$

where $Q + a := Q + \{q\} = \{ q + a: q \in Q \}$.

Then is $\hat{Q}$ always finite when $|Q| \gt 1$?

---

Suppose it's true for all $|Q| \lt n$.  Then when $|Q| = n$ we have $Q \subset Q \cup p\subset \widehat{Q \cup p} \subset \widehat{Q} \cap \hat{p}$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $Q$ is any set of twin primes, e.g. $Q = \{3,5\}$, then $\hat{Q}$ will contain all twin primes, and we think there's lots of those.

More generally, [we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime#History) that for some not-terribly-large integer $N$, there are infinitely many primes that differ by $N$. Put two such primes in $Q$, and you'll get back all of them in $\hat{Q}$.